# Fix CHARINDEX query issues

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Hello all I am having my query as follows where I am checking whether the value is having NULL or empty

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LSTR = '' THEN 0 ELSE LSTR END AS left_string, CASE WHEN RSTR = '' THEN 0 ELSE RSTR END AS right_string FROM table
cross apply (
    SELECT
           CAST(LEFT(colsetting, CHARINDEX('/', colsetting) -1) AS INT) LSTR
         , CAST(SUBSTRING(colsetting, CHARINDEX('/', colsetting) +1, 200) AS INT) RSTR
    ) ca1
WHERE
CHARINDEX('/', colsetting)  > 0
```

Initially I am having this but as I am getting some `conversion error` I have written the above one

```
DECLARE @setting nvarchar(100)='80/ '
SELECT CAST(CAST(SUBSTRING(isnull(@setting,0), 0, CHARINDEX('/',isnull(@setting,0))) AS DECIMAL(3, 0)) AS INT)

SELECT CAST(CAST(SUBSTRING(isnull(@setting,0), CHARINDEX('/',isnull(@setting,0),0) + 1, CHARINDEX('/',isnull(@setting,0),0)) AS DECIMAL(3, 0)) AS INT)
```

My setting values can be `80/80` or `80/` or `/80` when I execute the script what I need is I would like to display the values separately either by first query or by second one. Second one is giving conversion issue, first one is working fine but I would like to know is there any better approach

SQL fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/45e87/1

With both queries http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/45e87/2

Comment: @Learner when you say 'a better approach'. Do you mean performance wise?

Comment: Yes performance wise or any alternate approach with out cross apply

Comment: `ForgeRock.com` that is coming by default when I view sample fiddle

Comment: Which can fit in this line `SELECT CAST(CAST(SUBSTRING(isnull(@setting,0), 0, CHARINDEX('/',isnull(@setting,0))) AS DECIMAL(3, 0)) AS INT)`

Comment: Why would anyone downvote this question? It's actually pretty well explained. (plus 1 to even the score).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this (I used original table name from your sql fiddle instead):

```
select
     [left_string]  =   convert(int, left([productName], charindex('/', [productName], 0) - 1))
    ,[right_string] =   convert(int, right([productName], charindex('/', reverse([productName]), 0) - 1))   
from [ForgeRock] where charindex('/', [productName]) > 0;
```

Comment: Thanks Juozas. I liked this query

Answer (score 1):

I actually think your code is fine, but since I love a good cte, I will throw this one out here. You could try and compare:

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
     SELECT CAST(LEFT(Productname, CHARINDEX('/', Productname)-1) AS INT) AS Lstr,
            CAST(SUBSTRING(Productname, CHARINDEX('/', Productname)+1, 200) AS INT) AS Rstr
     FROM Forgerock
     WHERE CHARINDEX('/', Productname) > 0
)

SELECT CASE WHEN Lstr = '' THEN 0 ELSE Lstr
       END AS Left_String,
       CASE WHEN Rstr = '' THEN 0 ELSE Rstr
       END AS right_string
FROM CTE;
```

Comment: With out CTE can we do this in one line `SELECT CAST(CAST(SUBSTRING(isnull(@setting,0), 0, CHARINDEX('/',isnull(@setting,0))) AS DECIMAL(3, 0)) AS INT)`

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your logic, but in my opinion, less code often results in less readability. There are no prizes for using as little code as possible.